# How do I show the pwd at the top of a terminal?

Tags: lxterminal

How do I display my present working directory (`PWD`) at the top of a terminal? I do not want the `PWD` in the body of the terminal. Presently my `PS1` is `!:`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work by invoking lxterminal with sending pwd in backticks with the -t flag, like this:

```
lxterminal -t `pwd`
```

[image]

Now of course you wouldn't want to have to invoke lxterminal from terminal (that would be silly).  So you'll want to add it to your launcher panel, and edit the command properties of the lxterminal laucher to include the -t flag.

Note that this also works with (regular) terminal as well.